# Select points with lowest elevations and same x,y coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, point, elevation

The problem is as following,

I have a point layer with x,y,z coordinates. Some of the points have same x,y but different z. I need to separate points without duplicates (x,y) and in case there are duplicates select only the ones with the lowest z.
How to separate them and have a layer with only 1 point per particular x,y?

I have ArcView 10.0 license.

[image: Same points visualised in another software]

Comment: Have you looked at the [Find Identical](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Find_Identical/001700000054000000/) tool?

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve the problem because I need an automated way to sort the groups of identical points (there are 10000 of them) by z attribute.

Comment: An alternative approach is to do a table summary on XY with minimum Z but you would need to extract those out from the geometry, unless you already have them as a text file?

Comment: Problem solved. Btw I forgot to mention that the point layer was 3d shape.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is

1. Create a 2D point shapefile from current 3D point shapefile and remove duplicate points (Delete Identical)
2. Right click in the TOC and select Join
3. A window like below will open and set
    a. "Join data from another layer based on spatial location"
    b. "1. Choose the layer ... " > your 3D point shapefile
    c. "Each point ... " > Select minimum

[image]